# Ограничение движения мыши окном программы

Tags: delphi

Как в Delphi 7 сделать, чтобы мышка не выходила за рамки нашей новой программы?

Comment: А не нужен ли вам просто полноэкранный режим?

Comment: нет! мне нужно чтобы не воходил за рамки

Comment: @Hamfri48: жаль. Не завидую тогда пользователям вашей программы.

Comment: @Hamfri48, винлоки - прошлый век. Придумайте что-нибудь новое...хотя, у вас это вряд ли получится...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, есть такая функция [ClipCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383(v=vs.85).aspx). В делфи она тоже есть (вроде в файле windows.pas). Параметр - TRect - прямоугольник, в котором нужно держать курсор.

Эту функцию настоятельно не рекомендуется использовать. Также не забывайте обновлять область по мере надобности и освобождать ее, когда программа завершится

Comment: я ваще нечего не понемаю напишите мне скрипт и куда его вставить!

Comment: в делфи нет скриптов.

А куда его вставить, это знаете только Вы. Но если не знаете, тогда оно Вам не нужно.

Comment: > я ваще нечего не понемаю напишите мне скрипт и куда его вставить!

детский сад, штаны на лямках. Вы, юноша, php объелись? какие в delphi скрипты? Куда вы программировать-то лезете,  учите русский язык для начала, а то так и будете "не понемаю"

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое, и, пожалуй кривое, это определять положение мышки и если её координаты больше нужных, то кидать её в нужные =)

Comment: напишите скрипт!

Comment: в книге вот что нашел
var
   cr:TRect;
begin
 cr:=Rect(0,0,100,100);//100,100 - координаты за которые мышь не выйдет
 ClipCursor(@cr);
end;

Comment: А в куда её прописать в форму??

Comment: Советую почитать книгу "программирование в Delphi глазами хакера". Там все объясняеться, и показываеться.

Comment: А я вот не советую. Иначе ТС так и останется на уровне винлокеров, скрывания процесса из списка Диспетчера задач и запуска кнопки Пуск в полет.